# Symfony2 subform for non-entities

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a form like this to manage permissions.

```
twitter   sms   email    readonwebsite
user0    yes      no     yes          yes
user1     no     yes      no          yes
user2     no      no      no          yes
user3    yes     yes     yes          yes
```

The current way I'm doing this is using a foreach loop for each subuser and adding this directly to the form

```
$form = $form->add($subUser->getId() . '_twitter', 'checkbox', array
(
    'label'     => 'twitter',
    'required'  => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'data' => (bool)//original checkbox value derived from db value
));
```

and repeated code for `sms`, `email`, and `read` permissions. This doesn't seem very elegant. In the form processing, I would have to deal with keys like `1337_twitter` and `69_sms`. Is there a way that I can process the form like `$form[$subUser->getId()]['twitter']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Doctrine because you haven't specified which ORM you're using.
Do you have a `Permission` object? If you create a relationship between permissions and users that would be a lot cleaner. You could add `permissions` to your user form and it would be easy to manage.

So your permissions table would contain a record for 'twitter', 'sms', 'email', 'readonwebsite'.

You could set up your entities and form like below:

e.g.

```
// src/PathTo/YourBundle/Entity/Permission.php
class Permission
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;  // e.g. 'twitter' or 'email'

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="permissions")
     */
    private $users;
}


// src/PathTo/YourBundle/Entity/User.php
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Permssion")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_permission",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $permissions;
}


// src/PathTo/YourBundle/Form/Type/UserFormType.php

class UserFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // Add more fields
            ->add('permissions', null, array(
                'expanded' => true, // Creates checkboxes
            ))
        ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then in your controller

```
// src/PathTo/YourBundle/Controller/UserContoller.php
public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{
    // ...
    // Get your user object

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserFormType(), $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) 
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        // redirect back to some edit page
        // ...
    }

    // render some form template
    // ...
}
```

It's that simple :)

Comment: I don't have a permission table. I'm using an comma separated list in the user table to hold the permissions. Perhaps this is the better solution.

Comment: Trust me, it is! You might want to add more information about each type of permission. Having it in this structure allows for that. It is cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: An unrelated question for you. What is the purpose of doctrine's built in array types then?

Comment: Do you mean for example the `ArrayCollection` object? As far as I know they're just nice objects that make the job of dealing with arrays less of a coding nightmare. 
E.g. instead of writing this everytime

`$id = isset($array['id']) ? $array['id'] : null;`

Array collections let you just write

`$id = $array->get('id');`

They're also useful because they give you access to a lot of helpful iterator methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
... $form->add("[{$subUser->getId()}][twitter]" ...
```

Comment: I'm getting this error. 'The name "[28][twitter]" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":")'

Comment: @No_name: Add any letter before `[`.

Comment: Symfony isn't letting them do the [].

Comment: OP check this out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html